# Showing that a solution to an ODE is bounded without solving the ODE

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation: $2y'-y^2=-\alpha^2$ where $\alpha>0$ ($\alpha$ is a constant). Ons solution to this equation is $y(x)=\alpha$. Without solving the ODE, show that any bounded solution to the ODE must be bounded above by $\alpha$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to go by contradiction and show that this leads us to a contradiction, but I didt figure out what to do. Here is how I started: Let $y(x)$ be any bounded solution to the ODE ($y(x)\leq M$ for some $M>0$). For the sake of contradiction, assume that there exists $x_0$ such that $y(x_0)>\alpha$. Then $2y'(x_0)=y^2(x_0)-\alpha^2>0$. therefore, there exits a neighborhood $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$  where $y(x)$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: I wonder if working with $\frac{dx}{dy}$ should not be easier.

Comment: Have you tried using the second derivative? If $y'=y^2-\alpha^2$ then $y''=2yy'=2y(y^2-\alpha^2)\gt0$, that might be useful. If $y$ is above $\alpha$, then $y$ is rising with increasing velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints only. Suppose that there exists $x_0$ such that $y(x_0)>\alpha$. We want a contradiction.

a) Let $E=\{x; x>x_0$ and $y(x)=\alpha\}$. Suppose that $E$ is not empty. If there exists $x_2\in [x_0,x_1)$ such that $y(x_2)<\alpha$, then by the intermediate Value theorem we have an $x_3\in (x_0,x_2)$, (hence $x_3<x_1$) such that $y(x_3)=\alpha$, contradiction as $x_1={\rm Inf}(E)$. We have $y(x)>\alpha$ on $[x_0,x_1)$, and thus that $y(x)$ is increasing on $[x_0,x_1)$, Now $0=y(x_1)-\alpha>y(x_0)-\alpha>0$, a contradiction.

b) We know hence that $y(x)\not =\alpha$ on $I=[x_0,+\infty[$. Show that this imply $y(x)>\alpha$ on $I$,  $y$ and $y^{\prime}$ increasing on $I$.

c) Put $m=y^{\prime}(x_0)>0$, and show that for $x>x_0$ we have $y(x)-y(x_0)\geq m(x-x_0)$, (use that there exists $c\in (x_0,x)$ such that $y(x)-y(x_0)=(x-x_0)y^{\prime}(c)$ and that $y^{\prime}$ is increasing) and find your final contradiction (let $x\to +\infty$, and recall that $f$ is bounded).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I understand your answer now. The only point where I am still confused is in part (b) of your answer: can you, please, explain how to prove that if $y(x)\neq \alpha$ on $I$, then $y(x) >\alpha$?

Comment: We have $y(x_0)>\alpha$. Suppose that there exists $u>x_0$ such that $y(u)\leq\alpha$. Then by the intermediate value theorem, there exists $v\in (x_0,u]$ such that $y(v)=\alpha$; by a), a contradiction.